# how to represent a non-empty list type

Tags: list, ocaml, reason

I'm a big fan of creating data structures that make representing invalid states impossible, so I wanted to ask how I could represent a non empty list in reasonml?

Since it's possible to pattern match on lists like `[]` and `[head, ...rest]` I thought it would be easy to represent a non empty list, but I haven't found a way yet.

**Update:** Thanks to the enlightening answers below I was able to come up with something that really strikes my tune:

```
module List = {
  include List;
  type nonEmpty('a) = ::('a, list('a));
  let foldNonEmpty = (type a, fn, l: nonEmpty(a)) => switch(l) {
    | [head, ...tail] => fold_left(fn, head, tail)
  };
}

module Number = {
  let min = List.foldNonEmpty(Pervasives.min);
  let max = List.foldNonEmpty(Pervasives.max);
}

Number.min([]); // illegal :D
Number.min([1]); // legal
```

Don't know how you guys feel about it, but I think it's awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also define a new list type without GADT as:

```
type nonempty('a) =
  | First('a)
  | ::('a,nonempty('a))
```

Compared to the GADT solution, you lose some syntactic sugar, because the syntax

```
let l = [1,2,3,4]
```

implicitly adds a terminal `[]` but the `[x, ...y]` syntax still works

```
let x = [1, 2, 3, 4, ...First(5)];
let head =
  fun
  | [a, ...q] => a
  | First(a) => a;

let tail =
  fun
  | [a, ...q] => Some(q)
  | First(a) => None;
```

Otherwise, the encoding

```
type nonempty_2('a) = { head:'a, more:list('a) };
let x = { head:1, more:[2,3,4,5 ] };
let head = (x) => x.head;
let tail = fun
| {more:[head,...more],_} => Some({head, more})
| {more:[],_} => None;
```

is even simpler and does not rely on potentially surprising syntactic constructions.

EDIT: `::`, the infix variant constructor

If the part of the definition with `::` seems strange, it is because it is a left-over of corner case of the OCaml syntax. In Ocaml,

```
[x, ... l ]
```

is written

```
x :: l
```

which is itself the infix form of

```
(::)(x,l)
```

(This the same prefix form of standard operator : `1 + 2` can also be written as
`(+)(1,2)` (in Reason)
)
And the last form is also the prefix form of `[x,...l]` in reason.
In brief, in Reason we have

```
[x, ... l ] ≡ (::)(x,l)
```

with the OCaml syntax as the missing link between the two notations.

In other words `::` is an infix constructor (and the only one). With recent enough version of OCaml, it is possible to define your own version of this infix constructor with

```
type t = (::) of int * int list
```

The same construction carries over in Reason as

```
type t = ::(int, list(int))
```

Then if you write `[a, ...b]` it is translated to `(::)(a,b)` with `::` as your newly defined operator. Similarly,

```
[1,2,3]
```

is in fact a shortcut for

```
[1,2,3, ...[]]
```

So if you define both `[]` and `::`, for instance in this silly example

```
type alternating('a,'b) =
| []
| ::('a, alternating('b,'a) )
/* here the element of the list can alternate between `'a` and `'b`:*/
let l = [1,"one",2,"two"]
```

you end up with a syntax for exotic lists, that works exactly the same as
standard lists.

Comment: ooookay, thanks for your answer but I must say I'm a bit overwhelmed here. I did not even know you could write `fun` to shortcut pattern matching (that's what this does, right?). Is this syntax documented somewhere? What about the `::`, where can I see what this does exactly? Do I have to learn ocaml first for this?

Comment: The notation `fun ... => ... | ... => ...` is indeed just a shortcut for `(x)=>switch(x){ | ... => ... | ... => ... }`.

Comment: ok, so if you can use the infix constructor to sort of "concatenate" types, why not go for a definition of `type nonEmpty('a) = ::('a, list('a))`?

Comment: also, as soon as I introduce the `nonEmpty('a)` type (either my or your version) every single usage of `['a]` is inferred as `nonEmpty('a)` instead of `list('a)`. Why is that? Am I shadowing the definition of `list`?

Comment: You can indeed define `nonEmpty('a)=::('a,list('a))`, it may work even better because you get back tyhe `[1,2,3]` syntax, and can easily extract a list.

Comment: But yes, one issue with such definition is that you are shadowing the original variant constructor `::` from the list type. There is two way to mix harmoniously two types of list: either with type-guided disambigation: `([1]:list(_))` selects the right constructor. Orthogonally, you can define the exotic list inside a module/submodule and use the local open syntax: `Nonempty.[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 4):

You can use GADT for this use case.

(we can also add phantom type https://blog.janestreet.com/howto-static-access-control-using-phantom-types/) but it isn't mandatory

```
type empty = Empty;
type nonEmpty = NonEmpty;
type t('a, 's) =
  | []: t('a, empty)
  | ::(('a, t('a, 's))): t('a, nonEmpty);
```

How to use it

```
let head: type a. t(a, nonEmpty) => a =
  fun
  | [x, ..._] => x;
```

type idea come form https://sketch.sh/s/yH0MJiujNSiofDWOU85loX/

Comment: Note that the list constructor syntax `[]`and `::` requires OCaml 4.03.0, and hence BuckleScript 6.x. It does not work on BuckleScript 5.x which uses OCaml 4.02.3.

Comment: Also, there are a few layers of syntax sugar here and it might make more sense to know that `[x, ..._]` translates to `x :: _` in OCaml, where the `::` constructor is used as an infix operator. For construction it would be `x :: []`. If the constructors had ordinary constructor names, `Empty` for `[]` and `Cons` for `::` for example, it would be equivalent to `Const(x, Empty))`. That is how lists are conceptually implemented.